# Cannot use http only cookies when deploy my rails backend application to heroku

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, typescript, heroku, cookie-httponly

Currently I have finished backend and I tried to deploy it on heroku, but when I change api calls of my frontend(react typescript) to the new heroku.com url, the session just cannot work (can't save login status and every time I went to a new page it just needs me to login again), I haven't deploy my frontend react app now so it's still on localhost:3000, so here's my config/initializer/session_store.rb file and cors.rb file.
session_store.rb:

```
Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: "_web_forum", domain: :all
```

cors.rb:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
    allow do
        origins "http://localhost:3000"
        resource "*", headers: :any, methods: [:get, :post, :put, :patch, :delete, :options, :head], credentials: true
    end
    allow do
        origins "http://localhost:3001" #replace this with final react website
        resource "*", headers: :any, methods: [:get, :post, :put, :patch, :delete, :options, :head], credentials: true
    end
end
```

I am totally new to react and rails so if there's any code needed to update please tell me :)

I changed the domain in session_store.rb file but it seems unsuccessful. My cookie session uses http only cookies for authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Your `cors.rb` file is currently set to allow origins only from `localhost:3000` and `localhost:3001`. Once you deploy your React app, you'll need to update this to include the deployed frontend's URL.

Regarding your `session_store.rb` you probably don't want :all for the domain. Instead set it to your heroku domain.
Additionally since you are using HTTP make sure you set httponly to true:

```
Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: "_web_forum", domain: "your-heroku-app-name.herokuapp.com", httponly: true
```

And finally make sure you are including credentals in your frontend request. So it should look like this:

```
fetch('http://your-heroku-app-name.herokuapp.com/api/endpoint', {
  method: 'GET', // or 'POST', etc.
  credentials: 'include', // Important for including cookies
  // other settings...
});
```

Comment: Hi yes I use {withCredentials: true} for every frontend axios request for the session_store.rb file I changed the domain to my heroku-app but it still does not work. Could it because of my postgresql database? because I didn't install postgresql (just use gem "pg") in my computer, and when I deploy my app  I cannot use localhost in development environment, when I change back to sqlite3 this won't happend

Comment: If you want to use Postgres locally you definitely need to have it installed. The reason SQLite works is because it's a file based DB and so you don't need to install anything extra. The PG gem just provides code to interface with the DB but doesn't install the actual DB - You need to do that manually and then confiture it in database.yml. You could setup your app use SQLite locally and PSQL on prod, but if you want PSQL on both you will need to install it on your local machine.